# Drupal 7 WHERE using OR and AND

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

Writing a custom module trying to look up comments.  I have a SQL statement as follows:

```
    $client_comment = db_query("SELECT comment.subject AS comment_subject, 
comment.cid AS cid, 
comment.nid AS comment_nid, 
comment.created AS comment_created
FROM 
{comment} comment
INNER JOIN {node} node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_associated_client} associated_client ON comment.cid = associated_client.entity_id
WHERE (( (associated_client.field_associated_client_nid = '$nid') 
OR (comment.nid = '$nid') ) 
AND (comment.status <> '0') 
AND (node_comment.status = '1') ) 
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0");
```

Ideally, this is supposed to return the following:

[image: Screen Shot of results]
However, I get the following:

[image: Screen shot of results 2]

For some reason, it is only returning the "associated_client" result instead of the "comment.nid" result.  Here is the full statement I'd like to get working.  I know it's a SMH moment, but any help would be great.

---

Per request, here is the code I'm using to cycle through the returning array:

```
foreach($client_comment as $item) {
        print_r($item);
        print '<br /><br />';
    }
```

---

Here are 2 queries that print all of the data to the screen separately.  I want to combine these two queries in to 1 query:

```
    $client_comment = db_query("SELECT comment.subject AS comment_subject, comment.cid AS cid, comment.nid AS comment_nid, comment.created AS comment_created
FROM 
{comment} comment
INNER JOIN {node} node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
WHERE (( (comment.status <> '0') AND (node_comment.status = '1') AND (comment.nid = '$nid')  ))
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0");
    // Get the comments associated TO the client from Caregiver node.
    $client_associated_comment = db_query("SELECT comment.subject AS comment_subject, comment.cid AS cid, comment.nid AS comment_nid, comment.created AS comment_created
FROM 
{comment} comment
INNER JOIN {node} node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_associated_client} associated_client ON comment.cid = associated_client.entity_id
WHERE (( (comment.status <> '0') AND (node_comment.status = '1') AND (associated_client.field_associated_client_nid = '$nid')  ))
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0");
    foreach($client_comment as $item) {
        $client_comment_array[] = $item;
    }
    foreach ($client_associated_comment as $item) {
        $client_comment_array[] = $item;
    }
    foreach($client_comment_array as $item) {
        print_r($item);
        print '<br /><br />';
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `associated_client` joined in your last query.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one.  It is in the original, still same result, only 1 item returned.

Comment: are you using fetch or fetchAll?

Comment: Can you show code the executes and fetches?

Comment: @Pitchinnate - not quite sure what you're asking for.  Are you looking for how I'm echoing to the screen?

Comment: Yeah, how are you trying to go through the array?

Comment: Added for you @Pitchinnate.

Comment: Are you sure the other records have a comment.status != 0 and a node_comment.status = 1?

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes I am certain.  If I run 2 separate mysql queries, one for associated_client.field_associated_client_nid, one for comment.nid, I get the desired results, just not in the proper arrangement.

Comment: Have you tried just echoing the query and using something like phpmyadmin to make sure you have your sql correct?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, that is my next step.  I want to make sure that I am not just having a face palm moment.  I will post 2 separate mysql queries that give me all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it by using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.  Resulting query:

```
$client_comment = db_query("SELECT comment.subject AS comment_subject, 
comment.cid AS cid, 
comment.nid AS comment_nid, 
comment.created AS comment_created
FROM 
{comment} comment
INNER JOIN {node} node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_associated_client} associated_client ON comment.cid = associated_client.entity_id
WHERE (( (associated_client.field_associated_client_nid = '$nid') 
OR (comment.nid = '$nid') ) 
AND (comment.status <> '0') 
AND (node_comment.status = '1') ) 
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0");
    foreach($client_comment as $item) {
        print_r($item);
        print '<br /><br />';
    }
```